# Gtalk auto responder

Tags: google-talk

Lifemojo.com has introduced a new feature through which you can access the calorie content of any food item or the calorie burnt by any activity, by sending the name of the food item or activity as a chat message to calories@lifemojo.com (You would have to add calories@lifemojo.com to your friend list first)

http://blog.lifemojo.com/2009/01/03/calorie-search-now-on-gtalk/

Any idea how they made it? 
Im an asp.net programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMPP bots (GTalk is an XMPP-based service) aren't all that hard to write.

Here's an example - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=346